# decrypting in java using private key SSL

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, libpcap, handshake

I have read the pcap file in java and get the dump data, now i need to decrypt this ssl session in Java, any pointer will be appreciated.I'm using pcap4j for reading the pcap file.

**how can i decrypting the SSL Session in java, i have the info of private key and public key**

```
 1. I have a ssl pcap file, a tcp dump of ssl conversation
 2. I have public/Private keys
```

it is similar to decrypting ssl session with wireshark using private keys.

Comment: This question is too broad - you need to write a pretty simple decryption code (read tutorials, and there numerous examples on SO already) and a boilerplace code specific for your situation.

Comment: Agreed. Note that if the SSL used DHE (ephemeral Diffie-Hellman) then you need the secret or the session keys as well, as DHE provides [forward secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).